# How to split android app into lib + app

Tags: android, apk

I have an android project which is getting big and I want to split it into library and app (library - main functionality, App - Gui and custom issues). And I want to continue in development in splited mode.

First idea is to use subrepository for this. Extract packages which have to be placed in lib and put it in subs directory as a complete android project with manifest, and all the stuff

app/subs/libName/

Then at the and I can from the lib create a Jar and add it into project.

Is it correct, or is there any better approach ?
And how touse it with GIT ? One or two repositories ?

Comment: What are you expecting to gain from this? You're inviting a number of build issues into your process by splitting things out, and you will need to separately build/maintain the library. Unless you have relatively static components, or you have code that you share across multiple apps, this won't be much of a benefit.

Comment: I did something similar in android studio dividing project into two modules and separated svn repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with one android studio project. Inside android studio project you can add separate modules to keep things organized and reusable.

Changes on booth modules can be committed to one git repository. Use pull request to review changes if you are working with more people.

Comment: I would add separate repository and configure main (gui) to have dependency on lib. That way you can track changes in both. Later, it will be easy to create jar from separate repository (lib module) and most importantly version it.